# Lex: The server encountered an error processing lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm developing a chatbot on AWS Lex and I want to use Lambda function to branch my intent.
In order to do so, I created a Lambda as follows:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    
    console.log(event); //capture Lex params
/*    
    let { name, slots } = event.currentIntent
    
    if(slots.MeetingType.toLowerCase() === 'on-line') {
        
        return  {
            dialogAction: {
                type: "ElicitSlot",
                intentName: name,
                slotToElicit: "InvitationLink",
                slots
            }
        }
    }
    
    return {
        dialogAction: {
            type: "Delegate",
            slots
        }
    }
*/    
};
```

But as you can see, even when the function does nothing but log Lex output, I'm getting this error message in Lex:

> An error has occurred: The server encountered an error processing the
> Lambda response

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are trying to build a Lex chatbot using JavaScript, please refer to this use case in the AWS SDK for JavaScript DEV Guide. It will walk you through this use case:

[Building an Amazon Lex chatbot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/lex-bot-example.html)

Once you get this working, you can port the logic to a Lambda function.

Comment: I have the chatbot almost finished already. I think I just need to get my Lambda initialization and validation running to branch my intent.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Lex is giving you this error message because the Lambda function has failed during execution.

Enable CloudWatch logging for your Lambda function and check the logs after Lex has called it. The logs should provide you with more specific details about what's caused the code to break/fail. From there you should have a better idea of how to resolve the issue.

Feel free to post the output from the logs if you need more assistance with debugging the issue.